# What is result of follow code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is result of follow code :

`[] == []` in JavaScript? I had it on test and couldn't find solution.

Comment: This makes no sense, plus java is  tagged for no reason.

Comment: Run it in your console and find out.

Comment: write the entire code and check what happens

Comment: it looks like a dumbbell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is `false` because arrays are objects in javascript, so they point to different places in memory, and are so not seen as the same thing.